# How to display a background color on heading?

Tags: html, css

This is my first time designing a site. I have a created a slideshow, and it's working fine. It's just that I want my heading to have a background color so that it can be seen over the image. But I don't know why background color is not working.

This is my html:

```
<div class="slideshow">
      <div class="slideshow-item-container">
        <div class="slideshow-item">
          <a href="humans/embryonic-development.html">
          <img src="img/baby.jpg" alt="A newborn baby"/>
          <h2 class="item-text">The Qur'an on Human Embryonic Development</h2></a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow-item">
          <a href="humans/the-cerebrum.html">
          <img src="img/brain.jpg" alt="The Cerebrum and Its Parts"/>
          <h2 class="item-text">The Cerebrum in Quran</h2> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow-item">
          <a href="humans/the-cerebrum.html">
          <img src="img/ocean.jpg" alt="The Cerebrum and Its Parts"/>
          <h2 class="item-text">Where the oceans meet</h2> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow-item">
          <a href="humans/embryonic-development.html">
          <img src="img/baby.jpg" alt="A newborn baby"/>
          <h2 class="item-text">The Qur'an on Human Embryonic Development</h2></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


.slideshow {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 20px;

}

.slideshow-item-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400%;
  left: 0;
  animation: 20s slider infinite;
}

.slideshow-item {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

h2.item-text {
  margin-top: -48px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #2b5072;
  color: white;
}
```

Despite the background property, it's still not showing it. Here is a screenshot:
[screenshot of site with no background color appearing on heading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvRME.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you scrolled the text on the picture, you need to add the code below to make it overlap.

You can examine the snippet to test it.

```
h2.item-text {
  .
  .
  .
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slideshow {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.slideshow-item-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400%;
  left: 0;
  animation: 20s slider infinite;
}

.slideshow-item {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

h2.item-text {
  margin-top: -48px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #2b5072;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slideshow-item-container">
    <div class="slideshow-item">
      <a href="humans/embryonic-development.html">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/1640/380/any" alt="A newborn baby" />
        <h2 class="item-text">The Qur'an on Human Embryonic Development</h2>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-item">
      <a href="humans/the-cerebrum.html">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/1640/380/any" alt="The Cerebrum and Its Parts" />
        <h2 class="item-text">The Cerebrum in Quran</h2>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-item">
      <a href="humans/the-cerebrum.html">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/1640/380/any" alt="The Cerebrum and Its Parts" />
        <h2 class="item-text">Where the oceans meet</h2>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-item">
      <a href="humans/embryonic-development.html">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/1640/380/any" alt="A newborn baby" />
        <h2 class="item-text">The Qur'an on Human Embryonic Development</h2>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your images to the background image of your div tag. Here is an example:

```
<div class="square" style="border:solid 1px red; height:150px;background-
```

image:url('https://www.campsitecoders.com/img/google-seo-search-engines.jpg')">
Photo 4

https://codepen.io/susanwinters/pen/wvWjvRb